# GWT:how to create a war file from IntelliJ of a GWT project

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I searched a lot for getting a war file (which can then run on my tomcat)
from IntelliJ of a GWT project.

But the war file I get is not running on tomcat.

This is what I am doing , Please correct me where I'm wrong.

I create a New Java Project in IntelliJ , from 'Technologies' page I select 'GWT',
check option for sample GWT Project.Finish.

I have now the GWT project which is running fine if i run inide intelliJ.

Now I go to Project Structure.Artifact,click(+) button, Select Web Application Archive.
and add war,WebInf,.css,.html, manually from the path,
Now this is the page(Attached) I get .. I have a strong feeling that this is the place where I am doing things wrong.so attaching the screenshot

After this I click 'OK' and the from menu buil the artifact.

But the war is not OK and is not running in tomcat. giving 404

Please guide What I am doing wrong.[image]

Answer (score 0):

A question asked quite long ago. However, I recently stumbled upon the exact same problem and was able to solve it by adding the following snippet to the web.xml file in the WEB-INF folder:

```
<!-- Default page to serve -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>theNameOfYourHTMLPage.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Ater this I was able to reach the servlet by the name of the WAR file as usual.